# How can I avoid components shadow going top of each other in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

When I changing the dark mode check box, it's shadow goes behind the dateLabel. How can I avoid this?
[with shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnpRX.png)

```
if (isDarker) {
        dateLabel.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 51));
        wallpaper.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("light.jpg")));
        isDarker = false;
    } else {
        isDarker = true;
        dateLabel.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        wallpaper.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("wa.jpg")));
    }
```

Comment: Your doing custom painting, maybe, overriding `paint` or `paintComponent` or some such, but, you're not honouring the paint chain (all the work which is done by the super implementation).  Painting is actually a complex process and you must either call the super paint method before doing any custom painting or be willing to take over ALL the responsibilities of the the method you are overriding

Comment: Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) for more details.

Comment: Also, a problem like this really needs a [mcve]